# Correct configuration of SVN with Xcode 4.3.1

Tags: iphone, ios, svn, configuration, xcode4.3

When I´m adding a repository in Xcode 4.3.1, I enter Name in the name field, and select subversion from the menu, and in the location field (initially showing a template , I enter

svn://server.myhomedomain.net/aproject

Immediately a red status indicator together with the message host in unreachable is popping up.

If I enter the IP address of the server, then the red status does not show up, but later on, the repository does not connect anyway. But if I try with a repository from google it works fine:
   http://googledocs-cocoa-sample.googlecode.com/svn

I don´t understand what happend, I think the problem is the protocol, but I need Help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
**http**://server.myhomedomain.net/aproject
```

or

```
**svn+ssh**://username@server.myhomedomain.net/aproject
```